# Unable to enable experimental feature in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse, inverted-index

I am new to Click-house and have set up a local server. I want to create inverted index but as it is an experimental feature it requires `SET allow_experimental_inverted_index = 1`. The problem is  it doesn't work.

I use `SET allow_experimental_inverted_index = 1`, then use `ALTER TABLE posts ADD INDEX inv_title(title) TYPE inverted(2);`which gives `Experimental Inverted Index feature is not enabled (turn on setting 'allow_experimental_inverted_index').`

I have tried setting up an xml `sudo nano /etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/allow_experimental_inverted_index.xml`  But with no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the clickhouse-client, these is no session - so changing a setting in one request doesn't "stick".

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE posts
    ADD INDEX inv_title(title) TYPE inverted(2) GRANULARITY 1
SETTINGS allow_experimental_inverted_index = 1
```

Comment: Additional question once the inverted index is made do  i need the "SETTINGS allow_experimental_inverted_index = 1" line in every query or it will be used on auto

Comment: Once the index is created, ClickHouse will decide whether or not to use it at query time